# Python equivalent of java PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Tags: java, python, pbkdf2, hmacsha1, hashlib

I'm tasked with building a consumer of an API that requires an encrypted token with a seed value that is the UNIX time. The example I was shown was implemented using Java which I'm unfamiliar with, and after reading through documentation and other stack articles have been unable to find a solution.

Using the `javax.crypto.SecretKey`, `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory`, `javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec`, and `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` protocols, I need to generate a token similar to the below:

```
public class EncryptionTokenDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String time = String.valueOf(millis);
        String secretKey = "somekeyvalue";
        int iterations = 12345;
        String iters = String.valueOf(iterations);
        String strToEncrypt_acctnum = "somevalue|" + time + "|" + iterations;

        try {

            byte[] input = strToEncrypt_acctnum.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
            byte[] salt = secretKey.getBytes("utf-8");
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256));
            SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);
            byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
            int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
            ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
            String query = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(cipherText);
            // String query = cipherText.toString();
            System.out.println("The unix time in ms is :: " + time);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Token is :: " + query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting :" + e);

        }

    }
}
```

Should I be using the built-in library `hashlib` to implement something like this? I can't really find documentation for implementing a `PBKDF2` encryption with iterations/salt as inputs. Should I be using `pbkdf2`? Sorry for the vague questions, I'm unfamiliar with the encryption process and feel like even just knowing what the correct constructor would be is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Wrote this years ago, should be an OK starting point: https://gist.github.com/is/13a519282e676dca861e

Comment: Just a remark: the salt in your code is not supposed to be same as the key. Either generate a deterministic *non-repeating* sequence, or use SecureRandom to generate it; then transmit it along with the encrypted message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Python equivalent is [`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac). For example this code:

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac

key = pbkdf2_hmac(
    hash_name = 'sha1', 
    password = b"somekeyvalue", 
    salt = b"somekeyvalue", 
    iterations = 12345, 
    dklen = 32
)

print(key)
```

produces the same key as your Java code.

However, the problem with this code (as mentioned in memo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009682/python-equivalent-of-java-pbkdf2withhmacsha1#comment91054901_52009682)) is the use of salt. The salt should be random and unique for each password. You can create secure random bytes with `os.urandom`, so a better example would be:

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from os import urandom

salt = urandom(16)
key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', b"somekeyvalue", salt, 12345, 32)
```

You may also want to increase the number of iterations (I think the recommended minimum number is 10,000).

---

The rest of the code is easy to 'translate'.

- For the timestamp, use `time.time` to get the current time and multiply by 1000.

  ```
  import time

  milliseconds = str(round(time.time() * 1000))
  ```
- For encoding you can use [`base64.urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) (it includes padding, but you could remove it with `.rstrip(b'=')`).
- Now, for the encryption part, Python doesn't have a built-in encryption module, so you'll have to use a third party library. I recommend [`pycryptodome`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/).
  At this point I must warn you that the AES mode you're using is very weak. Please consider using CBC or CTR, or better yet use an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the great info adam. The information on salt is especially helpful. The API service actually provided this example to me with regard to salt creation so I can provide that feedback moving forward. Accepted and appreciated

Comment: Thanks again for this Adam; just to follow-up; what is the difference between `skc` and `tmp` in the above `java` example? I was able to reproduce `tmp` using the method you had mentioned but do I need an `AES` instance to create the `SecretKeySpec`? if not how would I go getting the equivalent value of skc?

Comment: Both `skc` and `tmp` contain the same key - the same bytes. We must specify the encryption algorithm for the `key` parameter in [`cipher.init`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init-int-java.security.Key-), so we use a [`SecretKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#SecretKeySpec-byte:A-java.lang.String-) object with `"AES"` for the `algorithm` parameter. It's basically the same key, just different objects.

Comment: Ah ok, so the actual bytes are the same but the `AES` field on that `SecretKey` object is what is used by the `Cipher` object? is there any examples of the implementation of that type of cypher in python?