# How can I port Java SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret() to Python?

Tags: java, python, cryptography, porting, pbkdf2

I have this statment in Java:

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 37, 128)).getEncoded()
```

And I need this to work on Python. Is there any way to do that?

I've tried PBKDF2HMAC, but i guess that's another algorithm.

```
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA1, length=length, salt=bytes.fromhex(salt), iterations=iter, backend=default_backend())
key = kdf.derive(password.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Any chance the answer here helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009682/python-equivalent-of-java-pbkdf2withhmacsha1

Comment: Are there any special characters in the password or are they all in the ASCII character set? I'm a bit surprised at the mentioning of `256BITAES` and the final parameter, 128, in the `PBEKeySpec`. If I'm not mistaken that last parameter means creating a 128 bit key, which is of course incompatible with AES-256. How did you test that the result is correct or not?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, I've noticed this strange key sizes incompatibility too. Password - 125 ASCII chars, salt - 128 bytes. Result key in Java - 256 bits / 32 bytes long. I suppose algorithm 256 rewriting PBEKeySpec 128. My key from PBKDF2HMAC have  the same first 16 bytes in 16 or 32 version. And they are differ from Java one.

Comment: @kar, thx, but I already tried this algo with no success.

Comment: I'd have to look at the source code, but it could be PKBDF1 instead of 2. It would be weird though because officially that would only support up to 160 bit output... I mentioned the characters because Java doesn't use UTF-8, but is compatible with US-ASCII.

Comment: This Python implementation [`PKCS12ParameterGenerator#generate_derived_parameters`](https://gist.github.com/bertramn/d22e88eba2ce432be016ab5d61595ab4) in combination with SHA1 might help you. The code is written for PyCrypto, but can easily be ported to PyCryptodome. The implementation is based on the algorithms [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7292#appendix-B), sections B.1. and B.2. In my test the result was equivalent to that of the Java code. But it would have to be tested in more detail.

Comment: @Topaco, WOW!!! Thx a lot! That works!